# Removing Knox and SElinux

Tags: root-access, stock-android, xposed-framework, samsung-knox, selinux

I am having problems setting the kernel to permissive (SElinux). I have already tried the `setenforce 0` command with terminal but it immediately goes back to enforcing as soon as I set the `setenforce 0` command. So I finally got fed up and decided to monitor what was actually going on in my phone by using a logcat. After looking at the logcat, I found a line of code that could be setting the kernel to enforcing by default.

Here is the code:

```
/audit   ( 6001): type=1404 msg=audit(1479393162.929:264): config_always_enforce - true; enforcing=1 old_enforcing=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
```

The `config_always_enforce` is set to `true` so that means I should probably set this to `false`.

Unfortunately I don't know where this value is in my system. Does anyone have any idea? I have a Galaxy S6.

Also, I removed all the Knox apps, but everytime I reboot, I get Knox folders reappearing and a file called `knox emulated` in the `/storage` folder. Have I not removed all the Knox apps?

I will post my logcat that way ya'll can take a look at it.

I hope you all can help me because I really want a custom ROM so I can use Xposed.

Comment: Alternate Solution: Try a custom kernel, if that helps..

Comment: They don't have custom kernel available for my phone as of now. My phone is a Straighttalk.

Comment: Here's someone who says custom kernel from a different variant will work: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/help/straight-talk-s6-sm-s906l-phone-costom-t3317269/post68785114

Comment: What about the knox?

Comment: @RyanNoles Wait a minute. What's stopping you from flashing a custom recovery and then a custom ROM?

Comment: I got a recovery, but cant get custom roms to load.

Answer (score 0):

If you want permanently change your SElinux status, you can handle the situation by changing two functions of `selinux.cpp` placed at `system/core/init` in AOSP 13 source code. You need to only return `SELINUX_PERMISSIVE` and `false` for functions `StatusFromProperty()` and `IsEnforcing()`, respectively.

For more information, I recommend to check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77497503/producing-a-user-build-of-aosp-with-permissive-selinux-policy) in details.